# How to use selector with multiple channels?(nio)

Tags: java, io, selector, nio, nonblocking

I am reading following tutorial:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html

I am feeling that I am didn't understand a lot of details of following article but I am trying to invoke example at the end of the article.

my final code looks so:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel channel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        SelectionKey selectionKey = channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        while (true) {
            int readyChannels = selector.select();
            if (readyChannels == 0) continue;
            Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();//cause of exception
            while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    // a connection was accepted by a ServerSocketChannel.
                } else if (key.isConnectable()) {
                    // a connection was established with a remote server.
                } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    // a channel is ready for reading
                } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    // a channel is ready for writing
                }
                keyIterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

As a result of this method invokation I see follwing stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.register(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:196)
    at java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel.register(SelectableChannel.java:277)
    ...
```

### update

my full code variant:

```
public class NioSelectorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Receiver()).start();
        new Thread(new Sender()).start();
    }

}

class Receiver implements Runnable {
    private static byte[] data = new byte[255];

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                data[i] = (byte) i;

            ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            server.configureBlocking(false);

            server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(9000));
            Selector selector = Selector.open();
            server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

            while (true) {
                selector.select();
                Set readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
                    iterator.remove();
                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                        SocketChannel client = server.accept();
                        System.out.println("Accepted connection from " + client);
                        client.configureBlocking(false);
                        ByteBuffer source = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
                        SelectionKey key2 = client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                        key2.attach(source);
                    } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                        SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                        ByteBuffer output = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();
                        if (!output.hasRemaining()) {
                            output.rewind();
                        }
                        client.write(output);
                    }

                    key.channel().close();

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Sender implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            SocketChannel sChannel = SocketChannel.open();
            sChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            sChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9000));
            while (!sChannel.finishConnect()) {
                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
                buf.put((byte) 0xFF);

                buf.flip();
                int numBytesWritten = sChannel.write(buf);
                System.out.println("sent " + numBytesWritten + " bytes");
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In console I see

> Accepted connection from java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
>   local=/127.0.0.1:9000 remote=/127.0.0.1:50940]

In debug I see that I cannot to enter into this loop:

```
while (!sChannel.finishConnect()) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        SelectionKey selectionKey = channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

This should be OP_ACCEPT for a ServerSocketChannel.

Comment: According your comment to Tsotne Tabidze answer please provide shortest example with channels and selectors. I cannot understand how does it work

Comment: You cannot understand changing OP_READ to OP_ACCEPT? NB this isn't a help desk or free coding service.

Comment: I just want to understand how does it work. all information which I read isn't clear for me.

Comment: I want to get byte from client on server

Comment: And what's stopping you exactly?

Comment: I want to get answer from you! I wrote code and this code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You need to ask an intelligible question before you can get an answer from anybody.

Comment: looks like you gloom. You understand that I bad at this topic and instead of help you want to degrade me

Comment: When you ask a question that can be answered, you will get an answer. Not before. You need to state what you've tried, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead. I don't see any of that. All I see is equivalent to asking for someone else to write the code for you. NB 'you gloom' is meaningless.

Comment: my question- I have code. this code doesn't work as expected. What do I wrong

Comment: If you're talking about how to call finishConnect(), see my answer to the question of which your other question is a duplicate, which you should already have followed up. You're only confusing yourself by asking several versions of the same question.

Answer (score -1):

In Java documentation it's written that register method throws

> IllegalArgumentException - If a bit in ops does not correspond to an operation that is supported by this channel, that is, if set & ~validOps() != 0

(Source: http://bit.ly/1lSBdX8)

I think you need to bind a specific port at first, and register selector on that SocketChannel. So the beginning of your code should look like this:

```
ServerSocketChannel channel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080)); // 8080 is the port you'll be listening
SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
Selector selector = Selector.open();
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
SelectionKey selectionKey = socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
...
```

Comment: You're right, he must bind, but it doesn't explain this problem.